# How to check if unattended upgradeis currently running

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I was wondering if there was a way to check if unattended upgrade is currently doing its thing (from a bash script)

I want to use a cron interval to run a script that will periodically check to see if unattended upgrades is running and, if it is, send a notice to a webhook.

(The target of the webhook will then not attempt to do things on the server if unattended upgrades is running).

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save this script and link a cron job to it, `ps -C` checks whether any process is using apt "which is usually for upgrading" and `grep apt` checks whether the output of `ps -C apt` contains a result.

```
#!/bin/bash

command=$(ps -C apt | grep apt)

if [[ -n $command ]]; then

    # will execute if the system is being upgraded
    # to be more precise, it will execute if the process apt is running

fi
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I wonder if there's a way to detect when apt starts and then run the script instead of having to check with cron.

Comment: then there should be a while loop wrapping around the whole script, it's a bit resource intensive:
`while [ true ] #new line
do #new line
# code goes here;
sleep 0.05 #new line
done`